# Using Google Sheets/Excel to compare 2 datasets for inventory discrepancies

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula

I'm trying to compare 2 sets of inventory data - one from my online store and one from my accounting software. There are basically 3 columns in each set - the SKU, price and stock quantity. I have some items in the accounting which are not present on the online store.

How can I use a formula to compare the two data sets? If the SKU is found in both sets I would need to check that the stock levels and price values are identical and the respective cells turn green, otherwise they turn red if they are not the same.

I've created named ranges for the relevant columns but not sure where to go from here

Comment: `XLOOKUP()` is best fit.

Comment: the color change thing can be done by conditional formating

Comment: A couple of thoughts.  (a) I would solve this very differently in Excel O365 than I would without dynamic arrays.  Which version of Excel are you using?  (b) If you want to apply conditional formatting, I would *highly* recommend performing the logic in a helper column and *never* doing my LOOKUP()s within a conditional formatting formula.  Conditional formatting should also be a simple formula like `B5>3` because circular references in conditional formulas is a leading cause of worksheet corruption, and is hard for Excel to detect.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.